# Get Specific Piece of Page URL with jQuery and REGEX

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm stuck trying to figure out the best way to do this.
Currently, I have a function that pulls just the filename from the page URL.

For example. http://www.example.com/example1/thepage.php?page=1/ will return thepage.php?page=1.

How can I tell the function to only return 'thepage.php', and stop at the first question mark?

The current code:

```
var pageName = location.href.substr(location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1,location.href.length);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the already existing JavaScript `window.location.pathname` which will return `/thepage.php` for the example in the question. I guess you just need to strip the first slash off.

See [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) on MDN for a comprehensive guide to that JavaScript object.